# UWP Geolocating service keeps telling me that im in Seatlle

Tags: c#, uwp

I got problem with geolocating. Bing Maps keeps showing me that i'm in Seattle (actually im in Warsaw, Poland). I don't know what's wrong with that. I have enabled location services in my laptop (Win 10) and also in Windows Phone Emulator. Map loads up nicely and when i click "find me button" (`appBarButton_Click` method) it centers my map to Seattle.

```
private async void getLocation()
{
    Geolocator gl = new Geolocator
    {
        DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
    };
    Geoposition pos = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync();
    Geopoint myLocation = pos.Coordinate.Point;
    MyMap.Center = myLocation;
    MyMap.ZoomLevel = 12;
}

private void appBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getLocation();
}
```

Comment: Be sure to 'set' your location in the emulator, because it will not use actual gps. It will take a location you set in the emulator location tab with a drop pin!

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that works for me. I first checked the "Location" capability in the app manifest.

```
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
if (accessStatus == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    var geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10 };
    var pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    var myLocation = pos.Coordinate.Point;
    MyMap.MapServiceToken = "MyKey"; //Replace with your key
    MyMap.Center = myLocation;
    MyMap.ZoomLevel = 12;
};
```

Comment: Still the same :( Location capability is checked. It drives me crazy.

Comment: Are you using a VPN or proxy service?